# How to replace one column (text words) in files 1 by its classified number in file 2

Tags: linux, awk, character

I have one question like this:

File 1 (very big file):

```
    fid  rsid activity  
    1 rs111 we drink
    2 rs112 we drink 
    3 rs113 we eat 
    4 rs114 we are happy
    5 rs115 we eat
    ...
```

File 2 (activity classification):

```
we drink  1 
we eat 2
we are happy 3
others 4
...
```

I would like to use the activity code to replace (or generate another column) activity name, to get something like

```
fid  rsid code activity  
 1 rs111 1 we drink
 2 rs112 1 we drink 
 3 rs113 2 we eat 
 4 rs114 3 we are happy
 5 rs115 2 we eat
 ...
```

how can I use unix command (awk e.g.) to do it please?

Many thanks!
Eric

Comment: how "big" is your files(in megabytes)?

Answer (score 0):

In general, one would use `join` for this kind of problem, but the "field" to join on is a bit complex. Using `awk`, you would first read the "activities" file to build a dictionary, and then read the "big file", inserting the activity codes as you go along:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { val = $NF; $NF=""; sub(/ *$/, "", $0); a[$0] = val; next; }
     { fid = $1; rsid = $2; $1 = ""; $2 = ""; sub(/^ */, "", $0);
       print fid, rsid, a[$0], $0 }' activities bigfile
```

Insert headers as appropriate.